# Writing to a kafka follower node

Tags: java, apache-kafka, failover

Is it at all possible to write to a kafka follower node? I ask this because we sometimes encounter the following situation - a particular host containing a broker which is the leader node for some partitions becomes inaccessible from the producer host, while actually remaining up (i.e. a network issue between producer and a leader host), so a new leader is not elected.

To create a contrived example, one can block a host or a port using a firewell. In my contrived example, I have

```
h0: has seven brokers running on ports 9092 - 9098
h1: 3 brokers running between 9092 - 9094
h2: 3 brokers running between 9092 - 9094
h3: 3 brokers running between 9092 - 9094
```

I blocked outgoing port 9092, and as expected, approximately 25% of the messages do not get written, and error out, as expected.

In the real world, I have seen a  host being  unreachable for ~5 minutes from the producer host.

Is there any way to ensure that the message gets written to the kafka cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to produce messages to a follower, from the [Kafka protocol details](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html#protocol_partitioning):

> These requests to publish or fetch data must be sent to the broker that is currently acting as the leader for a given partition. This condition is enforced by the broker, so a request for a particular partition to the wrong broker will result in an the NotLeaderForPartition error code (described below).

You can come up with imaginative solutions like setting up a completely independent Kafka cluster, produce there if the main one is inaccessible and have MirrorMaker clone the data from the secondary Kafka to the main one, or forward the data to some other host that has connectivity to the Kafka cluster if your use-case really requires it. But well, most options seems a bit convoluted and costly...

Maybe is better to just buffer the data and wait to have connectivity back or investigate and invest in improving the network so there is more redundancy and becomes harder to have network partitions between hosts and the Kafka cluster.

Comment: Yep, buffering is what I had in mind, and am implementing. Thanks for confirming that you can only write to a broker currently acting as leader.